What insect is this? There are a lot of them in my apartment, but they don't seem to be either cockroaches or spiders
I keep finding these things in my New York City apartment, and I am very curious what species they are. I thought they were cockroaches at first, but couldn't find any pictures online that would resemble these insects.
(Added later):
Thanks for a comment--I am now convinced that these are, in fact, spider beetles. Mine look somewhat dissimilar to the ones shown on wikipedia--they are black in color and round in all three dimensions, they looked like balls with legs when they crawled, which totally confused me as to what those things were! 

Where in the world do you live? Different insects are present in different places, that might help narrow it down.

You are absolutely right. How come I didn't think about it? I modified the question.

These look like spider beetles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_beetle

Why not write that up as an answer @Rich ?

These look like spider beetles. see here Spider beetles are about 1-5mm long and there are 70 species of them here in N America.
here's more info from whatsthatbug. "They belong to the family Ptinidae and are not considered true spiders or arachnids, but insects." They're not apparently harmful, so I would categorize them as "Mostly Harmless."

